# Bootstrap Validator - RegExp weird behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, bootstrapvalidator, bootstrapvalidator-1000hz

I have to validate a field that allows just words, spaces, and the characters "&" and "-".

The regex I'm using is `/[A-Za-z\s\b-&]+/g`.

Here is the code:

```
$('#register_validator').bootstrapValidator({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    fields: {
        name: {
            validators: {
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /[A-Za-z\s\b-&]+/g,
                    message: 'Invalid character'
                }
            }
        }
```

When I write a valid string and then I erase a character, it triggers the validator.

For example:

text: Jones -> OK

erase a char: Jone -> message: Invalid character

Is there something wrong with the regEx? What can I do to avoid this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with `/^[a-zà-ú\s-&üû]+$/i`

It allows the alphabet, extended chars, spaces and the special chars `&` and `-`.

Thanks!